# Location Based App using a sliding hamburger menu with buttons that will filter map (iOS MapKit) search results Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mapkit

I am using MapKit on Xcode to create a "nearby" hospital/mental health center/call center location app. I want the user to be able to filter the map's results. For instance, if I am looking for hospitals, I only want to see hospital locations appear on the map. So far, to do this, I created a sliding hamburger menu with checkbox-like buttons to use as filters. So for example, you tap the hamburger menu button and you check the box with hospitals so that you only get hospital results on the map. However, I must have messed it up somehow because when I get to the MapViewController, only a black screen appears. Please advise how I can fix this or maybe use a different method entirely to achieve the same goal.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var trailingMap: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var leadingMap: NSLayoutConstraint!

func viewDidLoad() {
    mapView.delegate = self as? MKMapViewDelegate
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionRadius:CLLocationDistance = 1000
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

var hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false

@IBAction func hamburgerMenu(_ sender: Any) {
    if hamburgerMenuIsVisible {
        leadingMap.constant = 150
        trailingMap.constant = -150

        hamburgerMenuIsVisible = true
    } else {
        leadingMap.constant = 0
        trailingMap.constant = 0

        hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false
    }
}


var mapItems: [MKMapItem] = []
var place = MKLocalSearch.Request()              //user's facility search options
var naturalLanguageQuery: String? {
    place.naturalLanguageQuery = "hospital"
    let place2 = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    place2.naturalLanguageQuery = "Mental Health Facility"
    let place3 = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    place3.naturalLanguageQuery = "Women's Center"
    let place4 = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    place4.naturalLanguageQuery = "Call Center"

    place.region = self.mapView.region
    place2.region = self.mapView.region
    place3.region = self.mapView.region
    place4.region = self.mapView.region

    return place.naturalLanguageQuery

} 


@IBAction func hospitalButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(mapItems)
}


@IBAction func callCenterButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(mapItems)
}
```

}

Comment: You're not calling `super. viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but I am still getting the black screen unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewController is subclass of UIViewController, so you have to use inheritance from UIViewController instead of NSObject

So, replace this

```
class MapViewController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

with this

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

also fix your viewDidLoad method by adding `override` keyword before `func` keyword of your viewDidLoad function. That's because you override function from UIViewController. You will have to call `super.viewDidLoad()` at the begining of this function. So viewDidLoad should look like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self as? MKMapViewDelegate
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionRadius:CLLocationDistance = 1000
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: thank you! I definitely needed to add these corrections! However, I am still getting the black screen